# Can Python install files into PATH?

Tags: python, selenium, path

In order to install Selenium, step 3 on ([this site](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) indicates needing to install the chromedriver file in your PATH. I am on a work computer that does not have access to the system PATH directly. I have tried listing in the local PATH (I'm on Windows 7) variable chain like so: C:\Users\mknerr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\mknerr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\mknerr\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\mknerr\Programs\ChromeDriver\

(The .exe is in the ChromeDriver folder)

When I run the script with webDriver.Chrome(), I still get a WebDriverException that chromedriver needs to be in my PATH. If anyone has an idea why this isn't working from my local PATH, I'd love to hear them.

However, my real question is when I distribute this script to the rest of my team, they will likely have the same issue since my script will be calling chromedriver, which none of them will have installed, much less in their PATH. Can Python directly install a program or dependency in the PATH so they don't have to go directly accessing environment variables? I can guarantee nobody is going to feel comfortable doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place chromedriver.exe in the same folder as the executable. Just run the program with the driver right next to it.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding -- which executable?

Comment: The executable being your python script.

Comment: Makes sense, so if I put together a package with a top level directory including a setup.py and another directory that includes all the python files in question, the chromedriver would go in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

In our internal automation framework, we actually just distribute the Chromedriver executable as part of the framework, in the same folder as the framework's entry point.

Then, whenever we need a browser session, we do something similar to this:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_location = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'chromedriver.exe')
context.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_location)
```

`chromedriver.exe` is the default Windows name of the executable, of course; change to whatever you need.

This avoids any user setup other than installing the framework itself. No messing with PATH or any other local files.